# What is the problem not showing the image??? Is there any location error?

Tags: laravel

[image]
Laravel image showing problem.I can't find where the problem happens

Image is not showing.I have tired using asset function

```
<!----------End Navbar Part----------------->


{{-- start Sidebar+Conent --}}

<img src="{{asset('images/products/p.png')}}" alt="This is a image">
```

I expect the image will be shown

Comment: clear your cache

Comment: Is there a space in your image's filename? `p .png`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot you added, it seems that you have a space in your filename.
The filename looks like "p .png". Check if there is a space and if so, remove it from your image filename.